tensorflow incompatibility with python
I import tensorflow together with keras into a virtual environment and i get an error ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
Previously i upgraded pip version to the latest and also anaconda3 to the latest version.Can someone help?Thank you
upgrade pip anaconda
import tensorflow and keras to the venv inside anaconda3 to be sure that it has been installed into the right virtual environment. I was to run without problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What Python and Tensorflow version do you have? I think I had a similar issue few months ago which I solved with something like pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.12.0

Please review the system requirements and confirm that all necessary dependencies are installed on your system. Also, look into this issue, as it might help to fix the problem.
